# Restarting nested notebook runs in Databricks Job Workflow

Tags: azure, databricks

I have a Databricks scheduled job which runs 5 different notebooks sequentially, and each notebook contains, let's say 5 different command cells. When the job fails in notebook 3, cmd cell 3, I can properly recover from failure, though I'm not sure if there's any way of either restarting the scheduled job from notebook 3, cell 4, or even from the beginning of notebook 4, if I've manually completed the remaining cmd's in notebook 3. Here's an example of one of my jobs

```
%python
import sys
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/Load CS Feedback Firmware STG", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except Exception as error:
    sys.exit('Failure in Load CS Feedback Firmware STG ({error})')
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/03 Processing Curated Technical/02 Build - Parameterised/Load CS Feedback Firmware TECH", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except Exception as error:
    sys.exit('Failure in Load CS Feedback Firmware TECH ({error})')
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/STA_6S - CS Firmware Success", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except Exception as error:
    sys.exit('Failure in STA_6S - CS Firmware Success ({error})')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you should not use `sys.exit`, because it quits Python interpreter. Just let exception bubble up if it happens.
2. you must change the architecture of your application and add some sort of [idempotency to ETL](https://academy.databricks.com/course/MID-DE-ETLP-v1-SP-C) (online course), which would mean propagating *a date* to child notebooks or something like that.
3. run `%pip install retry` in the beginning of the notebook to install [retry](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) package

```py
from retry import retry, retry_call

@retry(Exception, tries=3)
def idempotent_run(notebook, timeout=6000, **args):
  # this is only approximate code to be used for inspiration and you should adjust it to your needs. It's not guaranteed to work for your case.
  did_it_run_before = spark.sql(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM meta.state WHERE notebook = '{notebook}' AND args = '{sorted(args.items())}'").first()[0]
  if did_it_run_before > 0:
    return
  result = dbutils.notebook.run(notebook, timeout, args)
  spark.sql(f"INSERT INTO meta.state SELECT '{notebook}' AS notebook, '{sorted(args.items())}' AS args")
  return result

pd = dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory")

# call this within respective cells.
idempotent_run(
  f"/01. SMETS1Mig/{pd}/03 Processing Curated Technical/02 Build - Parameterised/Load CS Feedback Firmware TECH",
  
  # set it to something, that would define the frequency of the job
  this_date='2020-09-28', 
               
  env_ingest_db=dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db"),
  env_stg_db=dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db"),
  env_tech_db=dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db"))
```

Comment: I've added example code from one of my jobs to the main post

Comment: you have to create it. this is only approximate code to be used for inspiration and you should adjust it to your needs. It's not guaranteed to work for your case.

Comment: Ah ok, thought it was some type of system table like sysjobactivity on sql server

Comment: Nope, there are no system tables on user side of things :)

Comment: I'll have a play when I get a chance and let you know the results, thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @RG0107 did you have a chance to try this approach out?

Comment: Haven't had a chance so far, been too busy, but I will let you know the results when I do get around to it

Comment: @RG0107 did you have a chance to finally try it? ;)

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you. I did try it and it worked. I only got to test it on trial workbook as i ended up moving contracts at short notice